# Store first occurrence of "unique value" in the range cells (remove duplicates in text join)

Tags: google-sheets

Considering that some cells contain repeating values is there a way to get a result of unique occurrences.

For example from following range of cells:
[image]

Achieve the following output in target cell "9ll br1 8sd" (similar to what TEXTJOIN returns but avoiding duplicates)

Comment: Hi Volna, is that something you what to see/accomplish with the filter on?

Comment: Hello, @JacobJanTuinstra after some reading it seems like it is, but for now suggestion from Yagisan does the job. But thank you very much for the help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your TEXTJOIN example, you could do this:

```
  =JOIN(" ",UNIQUE(A3:A8))
```

The [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) function finds all first unique values.

Comment: This suggestion solves the problem. Thank you, Yagisan :-)